# How to implement view more option in recyclerview gridview last image

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Like facebook feed ,If images are more than 5 then remaining images count with + is showing as follows, [I would like implement same in my app feed](http://screencast.com/t/5895maaC8),How to handle it with recyclerview ,Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout like this in your adapter:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/simpleImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/simpleImageWithNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="+5"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In ViewHolder initialize these two images.

And in `onBindViewHolder()` check the position, if it is 4 then load **simpleImageWithNumber** otherwise load **simpleImage**.